# Flutter connect with BLE Device even after calling connect methods

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was trying to connect my application to bluetooth devices (which is ESP32) using **flutter_blue_plus** library. So in ESP32, there is a firmware that advertize bluetooth signal and my application should connect to that device when I press "CONNECT" button.

Here is the code for my connect button :

```
onPressed: () {
  flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));
  var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) async {
    for (ScanResult r in results) {
      print('${r.device.name} found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
      if (_id_controller.text == '${r.device.name}' && _id_controller.text != '') {
        flutterBlue.stopScan();
        r.device.connect();
        print('${_id_controller.text} same with ${r.device.name}');
        print(flutterBlue.connectedDevices);

        List<BluetoothService> services = await r.device.discoverServices();
        services.forEach((service) async {
          var characteristics = service.characteristics;
          for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics)  {
            List<int> value = await c.read();
            print(value);
            await c.write([73, 77, 65, 77]);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
  flutterBlue.stopScan();
},
```

so there after I press that "CONNECT" button, it is not trying to discover the services. After doing the debug processing, it said that my apps is not connected at all. Here is the dlog for my debug result.

```
I/flutter (28832):  found! rssi: -49
I/flutter (28832): GNG000001 found! rssi: -92
W/provisioningap(28832): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
D/BluetoothAdapter(28832): isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(28832): onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=8 mScannerId=0
I/flutter (28832): GNG000001 same with GNG000001
D/BluetoothAdapter(28832): isLeEnabled(): ON
I/flutter (28832): Instance of 'Future<List<BluetoothDevice>>'
W/provisioningap(28832): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832): 
E/BluetoothGatt(28832): android.os.DeadObjectException
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:543)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.clientConnect(IBluetoothGatt.java:1847)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.connect(BluetoothGatt.java:915)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at com.boskokg.flutter_blue_plus.FlutterBluePlusPlugin.lambda$onMethodCall$3$com-boskokg-flutter_blue_plus-FlutterBluePlusPlugin(FlutterBluePlusPlugin.java:342)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at com.boskokg.flutter_blue_plus.FlutterBluePlusPlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.op(Unknown Source:6)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at com.boskokg.flutter_blue_plus.FlutterBluePlusPlugin.ensurePermissionBeforeAction(FlutterBluePlusPlugin.java:727)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at com.boskokg.flutter_blue_plus.FlutterBluePlusPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterBluePlusPlugin.java:315)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7581)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/BluetoothGatt(28832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
D/FlutterBluePlugin(28832): mDevices size: 1
D/BluetoothAdapter(28832): isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(28832): could not find callback wrapper
E/flutter (28832): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(reconnect_error, error when reconnecting to device, null, null)
E/flutter (28832): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter (28832): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296:18)
E/flutter (28832): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28832): #2      BluetoothDevice.connect (package:flutter_blue_plus/src/bluetooth_device.dart:39:5)
E/flutter (28832): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28832): 
E/flutter (28832): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Cannot discoverServices while device is not connected. State == BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected
E/flutter (28832):
```

I think there is an issue at my "CONNECT" button. But I am not really sure. Here is the **[full code](https://pastebin.com/z8yZr0ej)**. Really need help for this. Thanks.